# Ocelot client certificate authentication on downstream

Tags: c#, api-gateway, ocelot

I'm creating an Api Gateway with Ocelot. I need to give a client certificate in order to authenticate to the downstream microservices.
I actually implemented some code in order to do this. I've added a DelegateHandler which iterates on all the InnerHandler until a HttpRequestHandler is found. Than I add mi client certificate.
Is there a better way for doing this?